# Star overlap with the border when star count is >=100

Tags: bug, chat, user-interface

When the star count is >=100 on a message, the star overlaps with the border:

[image]

[The message in question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25365994#25365994)

The star should normally be at the right of the message box, but here it's in the box.

Comment: Stars to the message in question will be helpful in seeing chat's reaction to 1000+ stars :)

Comment: +1, +☆ for obvious reasons